# Solr Spellcheck

Tags: solr

Solr spellcheck not working for some phrase queries having "stopwords".
e.g. "stopword to solr" if you remove 'to' then it suggest spellings for solr as solar.
Can anyone tell what is problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before **Indexing**. Do 2 things : 
i) You have to remove/comment **Stopfilterfactory** from both index and query in **analyzer**.

ii) Don't use **KeywordTokenizerFactory** because it takes terms as a whole string. Use **StandardTokenizerFactory**.

Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the documents already indexed. Most probably you don't already have **SOLR** indexed, or its frequency is relatively low compared **SOLAR**.
Try enabling spellcheck.extendedResults=true so you can see the frequency